# I have problems with Intents in discord.js v13.2.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js

After updating `discord.js` I got an error: `[CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.`. I quickly solved it, but then the following problem appeared:

```
throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
```

I cannot understand the reasons why this error appears, so I ask for help from you.
Code:

```
const { Discord, Client, Collection, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Why do you use discord.js v13.2.0, it hasn't been released yet, it is in dev build. Did you try using the stable discord.js v13.1.0?

Comment: I tried using the stable, but result is the same.

Comment: Could you try logging `console.log(typeof Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS);` and show us what does it say?

Comment: The error occurs when you pass `undefined` into [`BitField.resolve(undefined)`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/src/util/BitField.js#L143). However I don't see a way how `undefined` could get there looking at the discord.js source.

Comment: When I added to main script `console.log(typeof Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS);` it's just wrote `number` in the console.

Comment: Then that is the expected output, no issue there.

Comment: You can try doing the same thing I did in my [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/95iDOmH.png) and see if you get the same output in the console.

Comment: I got the following result: __[screenshot](https://imgur.com/KByJIMI)__

Comment: The `undefined` there is what is causing the problem. Note that the intents shown in your screenshot don't match the intents provided in your code.

Comment: Yes, I now understand my mistake. Thank you for your help.